# View changes after search and replace on Vim?

Tags: vim

I there a way to view the changes generated by search and replace in vim?

E.g. the following example deletes trailing whitespaces

```
:%s/\s\+$//g
```

but say, I am not sure of the regex and I am afraid it changed something that I did not want to be changed. But I also do not want to use `gc` instead of `g`, because confirming too many changes is confusing and takes a while, instead I would like to see the changes in a new buffer, as some sort of list. Is this possible?

Comment: If you used git you could use its diff command to see what happened.

Comment: Or you could write it to a separate file and use vimdiff, but you should be using git anyway.

Comment: @MattGregory could you point me in the right direction about how to use diff with git? I'm using git and I wouldn't know how to diff one file with a previous version of itself (should it be in another commit? or is there a simpler way without having to make a commit JUST for the diff?), I will also look into vimdiff thanks.

Comment: `git diff filename` to get difference in a file and `git diff` for all the files.

Comment: Not a full proof but why don't you use `:jumps` in vim session?

Answer (score 5):

There's an old trick that you can use to see the diff between the saved file, and your latest changes. You can see it with [`:help :DiffOrig`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/diff.html#:DiffOrig).

It boils down to this command:

```
 command DiffOrig vert new | set bt=nofile | r # | 0d_ | diffthis
    \ | wincmd p | diffthis
```

Once you've put this in your .vimrc, you can save the file, make the substitution (or any other change you like), and run `:DiffOrig` to see the changes. You can then press `u` to undo, if you're not happy with the results, or you can save the file.

This does mean you have to save the file before running the substution, but based on your comments, I think it'll be good enough for you as a tool?

You might also want to take a look at this page in the vim wiki for some alternative proposals: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Diff_current_buffer_and_the_original_file

Answer (score 3):

**Neovim** has a nice feature that highlights the substitution on the fly

```
"As you type a substitution  the results will immediately be
"visible in the edit window. This feature is best highlighted
"in this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sA3z6gsqOuw
if has("nvim")
    set inccommand=nosplit
endif
```

Another cool option is the plugin [NarrowRegion](https://github.com/chrisbra/NrrwRgn). It takes a selection and uses a temporary window to apply your changes, after saving it, the result is put back into your original text.